# Upload multiple files on a domino server with SSJS

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, ssjs

I need to upload multiple files (doc, jpg, pdf) and want to do this via Ajax. There are several description for clientside code, for instant [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax). So this part is covered well. But I did not find a counterpart description how to laod and store those docs with SSJS code on a domino server.

Can anyone give some hints where to find a description or may have some code snippets ?

Also it would be interesting to learn about incremental upload methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ever, it's worth checking OpenNTF. Here are a couple of controls designed for that, [YouAtNotes HTML5 Multiple File Upload](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/YouAtNotes%20HTML5%20Multi%20File%20Upload%20control) and [XPages Async Multiple File Uploader](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Async%20Multi%20File%20Uploader%20Custom%20Control).